# App works on iPhone device, but not on Simulator

Tags: iphone

So I tried to add OpenFeint to my Cocos2D game, didn't work (I have no idea why), so I removed everything I added.
Now my game (that worked perfectly before) is working on my iPhone device, but crashing on simulator.
When debugging I get "EXC_ARITHMETIC" on line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"APPNAMEAppDelegate");
```

In the main.m file.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Your details won't help us to help you.

I think that when you added OpenFeint you made some relations with xCode and now you have some problems ^^

We can't help you without having a good knowledge of OpenFeint AND Cocos2D.

You should try creating a news project and copy/paste your codes ^^

Good Luck !